# How to create Custom Google Search Engine not for Specific Websites but for Specific Keywords?

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I want to embed a Google Custom Search Engine in a website, and have been able to set one up following [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630963?hl=en).

The options that the Control Panel provides let you set up an engine that **searches through content of specific websites** using the user's search queries.

However, I want to set up an engine that will **search Google with the user's query in relation to a specific topic** by adding a predetermined keyword to the query.

For example let's say this specified keyword were the word "pink"
If the user entered the query:

> elephants

in the engine, it should return all google search results for:

> pink elephants

I haven't been able to set up this kind of engine.

Google's Control Panel for Custom Engines does provide a space to specify keywords for the search engine, but typing in the specified word here doesn't achieve the desired effect.

It narrows the search results but not to the extent that typing the search with the specified keyword into Google itself does.

Does anyone know how I could set up this kind of Custom Engine?